# Why is 'error: unbound symbol' returned why I run my array comparison algorithm?

Tags: arrays, syntax-error, runtime-error, scheme, lisp

Given a list of lists in which the first element of the list is a name and the rest of the elements are integers, I am trying to build an algorithm that compares the similarity of two sub-lists by summing the difference between the elements at each position in the list.  I am using a `let` statement in this algorithm, and when I try to run it, the following error is returned:

> Error: execute: unbound symbol: "arr2" [similarity-arrays, (anon)]

Why does this happen?

Code:

```lisp
(define (get-list name arr)
  (if (eq? name (car (car arr)))
      (cdr (car arr))
      (get-list name (cdr arr))))
(define (similarity-arrays name1 name2 arrs result)
  (let ((arr1 (get-list name1 arrs))
       ((arr2 (get-list name2 arrs))))
        (if (= (length arr1)(length arr2))
          (let ((x1 (car arr1))
                (x2 (car arr2)))
                  (if (= 0 (length arr1))
                    result
                    (similarity-arrays
                      (cdr arr1)
                      (cdr arr2)
                      (+ result (- (car arr1)(car arr2))))))
          #f)))
(define dust
  (list (list 'akko 11 3 7 5 4 1 9 8 10 6 2)
        (list 'Alex 9 7 11 3 6 1 5 4 10 2 8)
        (list 'Aron 11 4 1 2 6 3 7 9 8 10 5)
        (list 'carter 7 3 8 2 5 4 11 9 10 6 1)
        (list 'Connery 10 2 6 4 5 1 7 3 9 11 8)
        (list 'Embryo 11 8 9 6 7 4 2 3 1 10 5)
        (list 'Jaycee 9 1 11 7 10 8 4 2 5 6 3)
        (list 'jeeelm 11 8 5 2 1 6 7 3 9 10 4)
        (list 'Jodast 10 7 4 6 5 1 11 9 8 3 2)
        (list 'KingDolphin 11 4 7 2 6 3 5 9 8 10 1)
        (list 'Knowledge 11 8 2 9 3 1 5 6 4 10 7)
        (list 'ruben 11 1 6 4 7 3 9 5 8 10 2)
        (list 'SickLizard 11 6 7 2 8 3 9 10 5 4 1)
        (list 'XIN 11 3 4 1 8 5 7 9 6 10 2)
        (list 'ZIPF 10 7 11 5 9 3 6 2 4 8 1)))

(similarity-arrays 'Jodast 'Akko dust 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper syntax of `let` is:

```scm
(let ([binding expression]
      [binding2 expression2]
      ...)
  body ...)
```

If you had formatted it correctly you would have seen that instead of `binding2` you have `(arr2 (get-list name2 arrs))` with no expression. The error message refers to that no binding `arr2` exists. So I'll format your code properly:

```scm
(define (similarity-arrays name1 name2 arrs result)
  (let ([arr1 (get-list name1 arrs)]
        [(arr2 (get-list name2 arrs))])
    (if (= (length arr1)(length arr2))
        (let ([x1 (car arr1)]
              [x2 (car arr2)])
          (if (= 0 (length arr1))
              result
              (similarity-arrays
               (cdr arr1)
               (cdr arr2)
               (+ result (- (car arr1)(car arr2))))))
        #f)))
```

Now from R6RS there is no distinction between `()` and `[]`. They mean the same. The only difference is that it's easier to spot errors. Do you spot it?

In many implementation I bet you'd get errors at compile time. Eg. Racket flagged this as bad syntax before running it just by hitting "check syntax".

Comment: When I ran it (in repl.it) with the `[ ]`, it gave me the same error.  When I ran it with `( )`, it returned nothing.

Comment: @Jodast but you removed the extra set of parentheses... if should be `[arr2 ...]` and not `[(arr ...)]`?

Answer (score 4):

One thing you need to improve is indentation of your code.
If code is properly indented then it is easier to spot syntax errors.
If your code looks like below, then you have an indentation problem.

```
(define (similarity-arrays name1 name2 arrs result)
  (let ((arr1 (get-list name1 arrs))
       ((arr2 (get-list name2 arrs))))       ; <- wrong indentation, wrong syntax
        (if (= (length arr1)(length arr2))
          (let ((x1 (car arr1))
                (x2 (car arr2)))
                  (if (= 0 (length arr1))    ; <- wrong indentation
                    result
                    (similarity-arrays
                      (cdr arr1)
                      (cdr arr2)
                      (+ result (- (car arr1)(car arr2))))))
          #f)))
```

This would be properly indented code:

```
(define (similarity-arrays name1 name2 arrs result)
  (let ((arr1 (get-list name1 arrs))
        ((arr2 (get-list name2 arrs))))      ; <- wrong syntax
    (if (= (length arr1) (length arr2))
        (let ((x1 (car arr1))
              (x2 (car arr2)))
          (if (= 0 (length arr1))
              result
              (similarity-arrays
               (cdr arr1)
               (cdr arr2)
               (+ result (- (car arr1) (car arr2))))))
        #f)))
```

Best to **not** indent code manually -> use the editor/IDE to do it.